# Ошибка в Checkio или в коде?

Tags: python

Надеюсь здесь есть люди, которые тоже решают по фану задачки на Checkio. Столкнулся с решением задачи Flatten a list.
https://py.checkio.org/mission/flatten-list/

В PyCharme мой код:

```
a = []
def flat_list(array):
    global a
    [flat_list(i) if isinstance(i,list) else a.append(int(i)) for i in array]
    return a

print(flat_list([1,[2,2,2],4]))
```

выдаёт результат:
[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]

На Chekio результат:
[1,2,3,1,2,2,2,4]
и тест не проходит (переделал решение, когда тест прошёл, но вопрос именно почему этот код заворачивают с таким вот результатом.

Вопрос: почему такое разночтение кода? (версии питона одинаковы)

Comment: Попробовал сам написать в одну строку: `flat_list = lambda array: [j for i in array for j in (flat_list(i) if isinstance(i, list) else [i])]`

Comment: и как? на Checkio прошло тесты?

Comment: Лень проверять)

Comment: не хочется огорчать перед новым годом )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы зачем-то используете глобальную переменную.

Естественно, при запуске функции несколько раз, результаты будут накапливаться в этой переменной. И при каждом следующем вызове результат окажется загрязнён предыдущими результатами.

Вы у себя локально запускаете функцию один раз - и не видите никакой ошибки. А chekio запускает последовательность тестов, и уже на втором тесте ошибка будет обязательно.

Вообще, глобальные переменные использовать крайне не рекомендуется.

Самое смешное, что в вашем случае использование переменной даже не имеет какого-либо практического смысла. Вы могли спокойно объявить пустой список уже внутри функции. В вашем случае использование такого скользкого инструмента, как глобальные переменные вообще ничем не оправдано.

Comment: В Checkio я не встречал запрета на использование глобальных переменных. Глобальная переменная здесь в коде нужна, чтобы её не затрагивала рекурсия. 
И да, вы правы, это баг чекио, программеры не чистят глобальные переменные при разных тестах (я считаю это именно багом, т.к. код решает заданную задачу). Значения добавляется с предыдущего теста.

Comment: Необходимость глобальной переменной, здесь нужна, т.к хотелось сделать решение в одну строку. У меня не получилось довести до ума выражение: `def flat_list(array):
    t = []
    [t += flat_list(i) if isinstance(i,list) else t.append(int(i)) for i in array]
    return t`  пришлось решение в несколько строк делать

Comment: Если у вас получилось сделать в одну строку без глобальной переменной, то интересно было бы посмотреть.

Comment: Да, действительно, не обратил внимания на то, что у вас там рекурсивный вызов. В таком случае, можно создать вложенную функцию внутри основной, чтобы она шла уже после объявления списка, и рекурсивно вызывать уже вложенную. Называть багом checkio я бы это не стал - если вывод тестируемой функции зависит от чего-то, кроме явно передаваемых ей аргументов, то это проблема функции.

Comment: Дополнительно описывать ещё и вложенную функцию это не камильфо. Здесь хотелось показать, что логика решения этой задачи вмещается по сути в одну строку. У меня получилось это сделать только с использованием глобальной переменной.

Comment: Багом это называю потому, что пользователь не знает и не обязан знать как устроена система проверки решения. У него на вход есть данные и требования к данным на выход. Если код решает задачу, то это решение верное. По-хорошему, каждый тест должен запускаться в своей песочнице, иначе это должно быть указано в условие.

Comment: В задаче речь шла о том, чтобы написать функцию, и система тестирует именно эту функцию. Соответственно, весь функционал должен быть внутри функции. Если вы вынесли функционал за пределы тестируемой функции, то система не обязана это отслеживать.

Comment: в принципе тоже верно, тогда надо бы в самом чекио отбрасывать всё (или как то подсвечивать красным), что за предлами функции аки ошибку кода, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение

Comment: или написать, что использование глобальных переменных заперщено